# TimePicker in ListView pops up time selection interface again after changing value

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a view containing a model with a list of pauses. Each of those have a start and end.

In my page, i am using a ListView where I bind these pauses to.
So in each ViewCell there are two TimePickers, one for the start time and one for the end time.

If I change the start value, everything is fine, however if I change the end value something strange happens: After entering the value, the input popup closes. Then it opens again showing the value of end time and after that another popup appears, this time holding the value of the start time.

After playing around with various layouts, adding or removing NotifyPropertyChanged events, I still have no clue why this is happening or why. 
It kind of feels like a xamarin bug and it looks like the Focus and Unfocus events of all time pickers in the Cell are being fired.

Edit: Looks like it really is a xamarin bug: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4305

**PauseModel.cs (Shared Project):**

```
public class PauseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PauseModel()
    {

    }

    public PauseModel(DateTimeOffset start, DateTimeOffset end)
    {
        PauseStart = start;
        PauseEnd = end;
    }

    public DateTimeOffset PauseStart
    {
        get { return pauseStart; }
        set { pauseStart = value;  }
    }
    private DateTimeOffset pauseStart;

    public DateTimeOffset PauseEnd
    {
        get { return pauseEnd; }
        set { pauseEnd = value; }
    }
    private DateTimeOffset pauseEnd;

    public TimeSpan StartTime
    {
        get { return PauseStart.TimeOfDay; }
        set { PauseStart = PauseStart.Date + value; }
    }

    public TimeSpan EndTime
    {
        get { return PauseEnd.TimeOfDay; }
        set { PauseEnd = PauseEnd.Date + value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Note, that there isn't any real PropertyChanged implementation yet, I removed it in order to make sure the PropertyChanged event wouldn't be causing the misbehaviour. StartTime and EndTime are "adapter properties", which allow binding the values to a TimePicker element. I also tried using dedicated TimeSpan properties instead of the "adapters", this didn't change the misbehaving of the pickers either.

**PauseScreenModel.cs (Shared Project):**

```
public class PauseScreenModel
{
    public PauseScreenModel()
    {

    }

    public PauseScreenModel(bool prefill = false)
    {
        if (prefill == true)
        {
            DateTimeOffset todayDate = new DateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset.Now.Year, DateTimeOffset.Now.Month, DateTimeOffset.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset);
            Pauses = new ObservableCollection<PauseModel>()
            {
                new PauseModel(todayDate + new TimeSpan(11,0,0), todayDate + new TimeSpan(11,10,0)),
                new PauseModel(todayDate + new TimeSpan(13,15,0), todayDate + new TimeSpan(13,45,0)),
                new PauseModel(todayDate + new TimeSpan(16,40,0), todayDate + new TimeSpan(16,50,0))
            };
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PauseModel> Pauses
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

**PauseViewPage.xml (Shared Project):**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimePickerListTest"
             x:Class="TimePickerListTest.PauseViewPage">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Pauses}" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="80">
                    <Grid Margin="0" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="Start Time" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <Label Text="End Time" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />

                        <TimePicker Time="{Binding StartTime}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <TimePicker Time="{Binding EndTime}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

The Page is invoked from App.xaml.cs:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new PauseViewPage(new Model.PauseScreenModel(true));
}
```

So any help pointing me into the right direction would be appreciated.

Edit: The issue occurs on a LG K8 running Android 8.1 using Xamarin Forms 3.4.0.1008975 and also on an emulator running Android 6.0, however on a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 with Android 6.0.1 the pickers behave as expected.

Comment: Can you provide more detail ?Such as the version of xamarin.forms and test device?I use your code and it works fine.

Comment: Added the device and Xamarin Forms version to the main question. Which Phone were you using?

Comment: I use the Nexus runing Android 8.1 and my iPhone.I suggest that you can create a a new project and add two timepicker on the page without listview. Because  I don't think it has anything to do with your code.

Comment: In my original app where I stumbled over the issue, i have two additional time pickers besides the ones in the list view. These work absolutely fine. As I added to my initial question, some devices have that erratic behaviour while others don't. However there is already a ticket in xamarin's bugtracker for exactly this.